# Transaction dropped and replaced but token didnt come back

Tags: pending-transactions

Need your expert help.

I had few SNX tokens in my MEW. I tried to send them to my binance wallet. Being a foolish, I set a low gas.
Original transaction - https://etherscan.io/tx/0xe34d75435b843e791c0914b6ab2f29fe444dafbc2c9cdddf733bbf7ecb983b1c

I waited 9-10 days and seeing that it is still pending i followed instruction to send 0 eth tran to myself with same nonce. it was successful but the token didn't come back.
https://etherscan.io/tx/0xfd7384664c55dfb32ac8681b7d5ad3262557e66d686f59be192d0dd2c74968bf

please advice

Answer (score 0):

Odd. I'm not sure why Etherscan isn't showing the SNX token balance for that address - perhaps a bug in Etherscan when handling dropped and replaced transactions?

Anyway, if you check a different block explorer - such as EtherChain - you'll see the SNX tokens correctly listed for that address.

https://etherchain.org/account/0x65ecd8d862507830690a05c91f05fe09a86be40c

---

To double check, you can query the Etherscan API for your address against the SNX token holders:

https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=tokenbalance&contractaddress=0xc011a73ee8576fb46f5e1c5751ca3b9fe0af2a6f&address=0x65ecd8d862507830690a05c91f05fe09a86be40c&tag=latest

Gives:

{"status":"1","message":"OK-Missing/Invalid API Key, rate limit of 1/5sec applied","result":"**18878075900000000000**"}

Comment: Thank You Richard....what should I now do to get those SNX into a diff wallet as I am not seeing the SNX bal in MEW

Comment: I haven't used MEW for a while - is there a way to refresh or resync it with the current network state?